# Netsuite - Unable to get sublist line count

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm using a scheduled script to get the line count of a sublist on a customer record so I can loop through the list. The list items are a custom record type (SOW_rec) and are children of the customer. I am able to load the record but lineCount only returns a -1 no matter which sublist ID I try. How do I find the sublist ID where the sublist is in a parent-child relationship? I have tried looking in &XML=T but there is no sublist data in there.

```
 var companyRecord = record.load({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER, 
        id: company,
        isDynamic: true,
    });
    log.debug({
        title: 'companyrecord', 
        details: companyRecord
     });
    var lineCount = companyRecord.getLineCount('SOW_Rec');

    log.debug({
        title: 'linecount', 
        details: lineCount
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the  "Allow Child Record Editing" checkbox on the child record that you are trying to access with the `.getLineCount` command.

Also, as dcrs mentioned, the linecount command should be `var lineCount = companyRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:"RECMACHCUSTRECORD...."});`

Comment: As old as this answer, this should be mentioned on trainings materials. This helped me a lot when I was pulling my hair out when earlier today in which I couldn't seem to pull the recmach record on an Employee > Custom Record relationship.

Answer (score 2):

NetSuite Help Article 65795 details the naming convention for Custom Child Record Sublist IDs

> The internal ID for a custom child record sublist is recmach + > field_id_for_the_parent_field (for example: recmachcustrecord111).

NetSuite expects all lower case for the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for line count is incorrect. You're missing the parameter needed for the sublist. If this is a child record it will be linked by the field listed with the "record is parent" checked.

```
var lineCount = companyRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:"RECMACHCUSTRECORD...."});
```

Comment: After getting on with netsuite support we figured out you need the "Allow Child Record Editing" setting to be checked on the custom record type.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the XML structure of a Customer record (using &xml=T appended to the URL), I can see the sublist data there.  However, in a thoroughly effective effort to confuse, NetSuite has called the relevant XML element `<machine>` rather than `<sublist>` or something you might naturally think of.  So try searching for "machine" on the customer record after loading it with &xml=T - you should see several references to it (open and close tags for each sublist) each with `<line>` sub-elements.

Once you've located the `<machine>` elements, you will see each has a `name` attribute which is the sublist ID you're looking for.

Comment: I finally found the sublist ID in the customer record customize form XML structure. For some reason the sublist ID <machine> element was not in the regular customer record XML. I think that may be because the sublist is populated by child records. However the sublist ID still won't work, I get 0 for the line count when there are 6. Before I got -1 so a little better I guess.